# Popup dialog not showing details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dialog, popup

When i click on the new transaction button it only shows the popup dialog but not the details.I followed the tutorial exactly the same but my popup dialog still doesn't pop up the details in dialog box. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCmwb.png).

`Site.js`

```
showInPopup = (url, title) => {
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (res) {
            $("#form-modal.modal-body").html(res);
            $("#form-modal.modal-title").html(title);
            $("#form-modal").modal('show');
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: what tutorial you are following? It seems ajax failure.

Comment: this one 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3r6RfShv8m8&t=1671s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that you lack of the "space" in JQuery bracket `form-modal .modal-body`. The space means that you are selecting a child of div.

```
    showInPopup = (url, title) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (res) {
                $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res);
                $('#form-modal .modal-title').html(title);
                $('#form-modal').modal('show');
            }
        })
    }
```

-----------------------------old post----------------------
The ajax is success, or no window will popup. The problem is on the response.  Make sure you could see this page by visit `/Transaction/AddOrEdit` directly.Then the popup details will show.
[image]
[image]

If the url works you could try change the button to `onclick="showInPopup('/Transaction/AddOrEdit','New Transaction')"` to see if it works.

Comment: the url can works but when i change the button it still doesn't show the popup details.
these are the code that i made changes.  
`<a onclick="showInPopup('/Transaction/AddOrEdit','New Transaction')" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fas fa-random"></i> New Transaction </a>`

Comment: @ray I compared the code and find a difference. You could try my modified answer.

Comment: I used your code just now but the button is gone. can you send me your code so i can make the comparison?

Comment: @ray I just test with the code from video shared github link. Make sure the  "AddOrEdit.cshtml" is exactly same as the sample. It has the button https://github.com/CodAffection/jQuery-Ajax-with-ASP.NET-Core-MVC-using-Modal-PopUp/blob/main/jQuery%20Ajax%20CRUD/jQuery%20Ajax%20CRUD/Views/Transaction/AddOrEdit.cshtml

Comment: @ray please help following instruction :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers